# How can I use the exact word "will" in a sentence about past?

Tags: past-tense, future

Last week our teacher gave us an assignment to find a usage for the word "will" in a sentence about past.

He also told us that it doesn't have anything to do with *would* and it's rarely used.

Comment: he last updated his will last year

Comment: It's easy to use a noun - 'He no longer had the will to live and he succumbed' but I think your requirement is for a verb.

Comment: 'Will' is not always used as a modal. 'Did you will for this to happen?' shows the will = wish = desire intransitive verb incarnation. There are other non-modal usages: 'Did she will (= leave) her estate to charity?' / 'Did the ancient rulers will (= decree) this?'

Answer (score 5):

Your teacher gives you some interesting puzzles to solve!

Anyway, one of the functions of *will* is to express confidence or certainty about a situation. This situation can be in the past. So, if you come home after school and your mother says:

> Someone phoned this morning, but I couldn't answer because I was in
>   the shower.

You can reply:

> Oh, that will have been my teacher. He said he tried to call you, but
>   no luck.

You can use the *will+perfect* construction in a similar way in sentences such as:

> You will have recently received a letter from the school about your
>   son's behaviour in class.

You can impress your teacher by telling him or her that this use of *will* is called *epistemic modality* by *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (p188). It gives the example:

> They will have made their decision last week.

Comment: This modality uses 'will' to predict what must have happened in the past.

Comment: +1 There's also the lexical verb *will* as in "I willed them to stop" etc

Answer (score -1):

That's a crazy request by your teacher unless you use will as a noun: as in your/my "will". That's as in an intent or desire to do something, or a piece of paper that lets your lawyer know which kid you loved the least.

As a noun, use any of these:

1. It was my will to (do something).
2. Were it my will to do so, I would have (done something).
3. In my will, I left my mistress everything.

I'm guessing your teaching wants a verb usage... So, you'd need an introductory clause*.

Example 1: "Yesterday, I told the flight attendant that I will smoke in the lavatory."

Example 2: "Two years ago, I told my teacher that I will finish my dissertation. And I have."

*An introductory clause provides background information for the main bit of a sentence. Here we put that information in the past.

Bottom line: "will" is for future tense, so an introductory clause is the only way to put it in the past.

Anyone know another way? I can't think of one.